# Hover on href tag and icon jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, haml

I have a side navbar list with an icon and a link. When I hover over the a tag the hover lights up, but the icon does not. The icon only lights up when I hover over the icon directly, and not the a tag. I want the icon to light up when I hover over the link. I have used jQuery to add an active class on my icon. I have a default icon(no light) and an active icon(light on hover). If I remove the i in the jQuery and just have `li>a` it does not light the icon.

css

```
    .nav.nav-main {
      background: #293041;
    }
    .nav.nav-main li > a {
      color: #aaccff;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 300;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    .nav.nav-main li > a i {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .nav.nav-main li > a span {
      padding-top: 3px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav.nav-main li > a.active,
    .nav.nav-main li > a:hover {
      background: #374356;
      color: #ffffff;

}
```

jQuery

```
$(".nav.nav-main li>a>i").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
  );
```

haml

```
%ul.nav.nav-main.nav-sidebar
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a{ href: 'javascript:void(0)' }
        %i.pull-left.fu.fu-lg.fu-alumni
        %span.pull-right.badge.badge-warning 1
        Alumni
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle to replicate your problem

Comment: just change your `jquery` like `$(".nav.nav-main li>a").hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css way also works, but im going to use this solution

```
$(".nav.nav-main li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('active');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you a different approach. Why don't use the `li:hover`instead of jQuery?

```
.nav.nav-main li:hover > a,
.nav.nav-main li:hover > a > i{
      background: #374356;
      color: #ffffff;
}
```